# How can I create multiple dashboards with Open Atrium?

Tags: distributions, dashboard

By default each Open Atrium group has its own dashboard. What I'd like to do is to create multiple dashboards (pages?) for each group. My goal is to create separated dashboards with different contents, just like website's pages. Any idea on how to do this with Open Atrium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a normal PHP node and used that one as a Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Users with sufficient permissions should see an "Add custom" link on the Dashboard.  This link lets you create additional Dashboards for a single group, each with its own content and layout.

[image: Open Atrium Dashboard's "Add custom" link]

Comment: OP want to *create separated dashboards with different contents, just like website's pages*

Comment: I don't understand; my answer explains how to create separate dashboard pages with different content.  Could you elaborate?